# Meaning of casting pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code

```
int a[5] = {20,-90, 450, -37,87};
int *p;

for(p=a; (char *)p <((char*)a+sizeof(int)*5 );) // this line I don't understand
      *p++ = ++*p<60?*p:0;

for(p=a; (char *)p <( (char*)a+sizeof(int)*5 );)
      printf("\n%d", *p++);
```

I can't understand the condition of the loop, what is the meaning of casting the pointer to char *?
What will happen?

(I know what the body of the loop does)

Thank you very much

Comment: How about sharing what the code does?

Comment: The point of the cast is so that you iterate through the array one *byte* at a time instead of one *int* at a time - that's all...

Comment: @PaulR I expect *p++ to increment the pointer by sizeof(int), not by sizeof(char)

Comment: Oh yes - my bad - in that case the casts are pointless and the code could be written much more simply

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of that cast is to ensure that when you add `sizeof(int)` to the pointer, it adds the correct amount of bytes.

It would have been better to leave off the cast, and leave off the `sizeof`. Pointer arithmetic will do this for you already.

It would have been even better to write readable code in the first place. ;-)

**Edit:**

I would also consider using a conditional like this, to address the concern about the array size changing:

```
p < (a+ (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])))
```

Using `sizeof(a[0])` also protects you in case the array type changes.

Note also that the code produces the following warning:

```
/tmp/foo.c:9:11: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'p'
                 [-Wunsequenced]
    *p++ = ++*p<60?*p:0;
      ^       ~
1 warning generated.
```

Answer (score 3):

For what ever crazy reason there is ..

`(char *)p` says lets take `p` and pretend that it is a pointer to char

`(char*)a` says the same thing about `a`

`sizeof(int)*5` is a value that represents the size of 5 `int`

So that `(char *)p <((char*)a+sizeof(int)*5)` is a condition saying that `p` (pretending to be a char pointer) needs to be less than 5 `int` lengths past the start of `a` (pretending to be a char pointer)

So they don't want `p` to go past the end of the `int` array `a`.

Which is a crazy way of doing it, and is **very fragile** as if you change the size of `a` then the whole thing breaks.

However this `*p++ = ++*p<60?*p:0;` scares me even more than the condition, and I am thinking that it might be `Undefined Behaviour` or some such (I'm not up on my C right now)

Technically I think it increments `p`, checks the value at that location, if it is less than 60, take that value (or zero if it is over 60), stuffs it into where `p` is pointing to and then increments `p`.  So it seems to get 2 increments of `p` for each loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much.
That's the kind of questions that I need to solve in my exam:(
It makes me crazy that in real time I shouldn't write like this, so why teach it ??!
Again thank you